IIn video games, are slight damage details, like say on a tank, made by modifying the geometry or by using textures?
Here are images of real tanks and I drew arrows into the places with slight damage:

In video games, are those made by modifying the geometry or with textures?

There are generally more than one way to skin a cat, and it depends often why you need to have the cat skinned. This site works better when you tell us what you need, why and what ypuve tried so that we can provide an answer to your specifics.

If the real life damage looks like you could draw it on with (real life) paint it's probably going to be modeled in game with textures. If thats not possible it's more likely going to need to use changes to the mesh. However there are other options such as using shaders. PS I laughed at @Vaillancourt's turn of phrase, very well done sir...

The amount of detail that goes into visually representing damage in a game will heavily depend on the type of game, the platform that the game is running on, and the budget for the game. For example, highly detailed damage is not critical in an RTS where the camera is usually high above the units. Damage is likely to be more detailed in a PC or console game than in a mobile game, because mobile devices have less rendering power and limited battery life.
Some games don't show location-specific damage. In these games, the unit doesn't change appearance until it's taken a certain amount of damage, and then the unit's whole texture is swapped out with a texture that has scorch marks, bullet holes, etc to indicate that the unit is very beat up. Sometimes, the mesh will also be swapped with a version that has deformations like warped armor plates, broken antennae, missing panels, etc.
In more modern games with more sophisticated graphics, location-specific damage can be represented in a variety of ways:

Decal textures can be used to create bullet holes, scorch marks, dents, and other such damage that doesn't modify the underlying mesh (geometry). Bullet hole and dent decals may include a normal map or parallax map to make the damage look more three-dimensional. (A displacement map could theoretically be used to make the decal actually manipulate the vertices of the underlying mesh, but this only works when the geometry is sufficiently detailed and could easily create unrealistic-looking deformations when used in the wrong place.)
For objects built with multiple meshes and/or materials, the game might swap out meshes and materials individually to represent damage in certain areas. As an example, a tank might consist of two meshes, one for the body and one for the turret. If the turret takes a direct hit that causes heavy damage, the game could swap out the turret mesh and material without changing the mesh or material of the body. A more detailed game might have each set of treads be separate from the body and turret.

